# Fix initial values of some controls in nloptr optimizer in R

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

I am able to run non-linear optimization problem using `nloptr` in R by giving initial values of parameters/controls.

Is there a way to "fix" some of the initial values, for example, let's assume the initial values of the controls are 0.5,0.33,0.5,0.1,10 . `nloptr` will vary these to minimize the objective function.

If I would like to set a condition for the variables such that "any initial value that is less than 0.4 should not be varied; for the above values, it is 0.33 and 0.1, can `nloptr`only vary the other controls to optimize the objective function?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the lower and upper bound to the same value, the corresponding variable will be fixed. In general it is a good idea to provide reasonable bounds for the other variables.

Comment: I tried to set the lb and ub as 0 for some variables.  I get an error about "memory being corrupt". It does not like it.

Comment: Unless you are doing something wrong this looks like a bug to me.

Comment: It crashes the program when the lb and ub are set to 0 for a variable. It seems it does not allow this masking! @ErwinKalvelagen

Comment: It works for me. Make sure all functions and gradients can be evaluated at your initial point. Also make sure your initial point obeys all bounds (including the fixed ones). Take my word for it: fixing variables by setting `lb=ub` is a correct strategy.

Comment: Can I share my code snippet with you? Is it possible to share the email id? it's kinda big for me to share here. @ErwinKalvelagen

Comment: No thanks. That would be real work, so I don't want to spend my precious non-billable hours on that.

Comment: ok no problem. I understand. Your answer does not help in my case. I will keep trying.